# f:convertNumber unexpectedly increments/decrements float value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, floating-point, converters

I have a `float` property bound to `<h:inputText>`. For long values, it was automatically converting the values to exponential notation. I tried to use `<f:convertNumber>` to avoid the exponential value presentation. The value can be of two given below.

- Format 1:  <18 digits>
- Format 2:  <14 optional digits>.<3 option decimals>

I tried using the converter as below:

```
<f:convertNumber pattern="####.###" />
```

It is working for number up to 8 digits long, but after that the value is converted into some unexpected value. For example if I give value `12345678` in text box it is converted properly. But if I give `1234567899` the value gets converted into `1234567936`.  And if give value `1234567899.123`, still it is converted to `1234567936`.

If anyone could please shed light on this issue and let me know what am I doing would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell: [floating-point-gui.de](http://floating-point-gui.de)

If you value precision, you should be using `java.math.BigDecimal` instead of `float`/`double`/`java.lang.Float`/`java.lang.Double`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and suggestion. Very awesome article. I would try this!

Comment: And, did you succeed?

Comment: Hi BaluC, I converted my data type from float to BigDecimal and hence it is working fine now.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I have did it! :)